# Compiling nfdump with --enable-compat15

Tags: linux, networking, compilation

When trying to process netflow data with nfdump I get an error: "Can't process nfdump 1.5.x block type 1. Add --enable-compat15 to compile compatibility code. Skip block." I tried compiling it several times but to no avail. I always get the same error. Where exactly do I need to add that parameter? I tried to adding it to ./configure --enable-compat15, but it makes no difference. Must I add it some place else? Anyone encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out. ./configure --enable-compat15 is correct, but you have to delete all the direcotory and extract from tar.gz again, if you had ran make previously in that directory. Now it works.